# Speech to text web api returns different result on desktop vs mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, speech-recognition

I am using the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) to convert speech to text with following code:

```
const SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.onresult = (ev) => {
  const text = [...ev.results].reduce(
      (a, e) =>
        a + [...e].reduce((word, { transcript: t }) => `${word}${t}`, ''),
      '',
    );
  }
  this.setState({ speechText: text });
};
```

This works perfect on desktop with following result from the api:

[image]

But on mobile the api result is as follows:

[image]

Please ignore the content (transcript) from the above screenshots. The behaviour on desktop is as it should be but on mobile this results in a lot of duplication of content as the result has duplicate `SpeechRecognitionResult` values. I am not sure why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Also, the `isFinal` is `true` on desktop once user stops speaking but on mobile is always `true`.

Comment: Is it?  The mobile is just providing multiple alternates that it has 0 confidence in.  What do you want to happen?

Comment: I was doing this the wrong way. Just figured out the proper solution that doesn't require reduce().

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to retrieve the result on mobile and desktop:

```
recognition.onresult = (ev) => {
  let noteContent = '';
  const current = ev.resultIndex;

  // Get the transcript
  const { transcript } = ev.results[current][0];

  // Append the current transcript to previous Note
  noteContent += transcript;

  this.setState({ speechText: noteContent });
};
```